# cocos2d-x use pugixml to parse xml on android ERROR 'void* pugi::impl::(anonymous namespace)::xpath_allocator::allocate(size_t)'

Tags: android, c++, xml-parsing, cocos2d-x

I use pugixml parse xml, it's work fine on ios. However, when I change to android, use './build_native.sh' (cocos2d-x for android) to build my project. There are some error:

```
pugi/pugixml.cpp: In member function 'void* pugi::impl::(anonymous namespace)::xpath_allocator::allocate(size_t)'
pugi/pugixml.cpp:5722:26: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

someone can help me. thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tryed the `-fexceptions`? Maybe using it you get additional and valuable information to track the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Enable exception handling using -fexceptions, if your platform supports it
2. Disable exception handling in pugixml by adding `#define PUGIXML_NO_EXCEPTIONS` to `pugiconfig.hpp` or to your build settings.